# Armature deform with automatic weights creates wrong vertex groups

Tags: rigging, armature, vertex-groups

I'm trying to set armature to humans body object. But I have a problem, when I setting parent to armature deform with automatic weights, it's creates wrong vertex groups.

Before <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>–<kbd>P</kbd>
[image: Before Ctrl+P]

After appling automatic weights
[image: After appling authomatic weights]

And I understand that the reason is in wrong vertex groups.

For example this points relates to shin.R, but there are more points from left leg
[image: For example this points relates to shin.R, but there are more points from left leg]

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Here is a file with a [model](https://pasteall.org/media/e/a/ea18550f02e57fc33e56a94b1ff0907c.blend)!

Comment: hello please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Try recalculating normals in the mesh before parenting. that’s the usual reason when mine fails like that b

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems with your mesh. edit it. Go to vertex select. select all. recalculate normals. (shift n) remove duplicate verts. (m and select “by distance”)